What is the right way to check a MOSFET's SOA curve?
I'm trying to figure out if a P-MOSFET can handle 2A of current in DC.
I've already found two ways to check it based on the MOSFET SOA curve.
I'm using the FDS4685, with 24V input. I need to know if it can handle 2A in DC mode. The images below are the two possible answers I've found on the internet. The RDS(on) used was 42mOhm.


As you can see both images are the same SOA graph for the given MOSFET.
The first image uses Vds = Id x Rds(on) to find the Vds value on the graph, which is approx 84mV. (2A x 42mOhm).
The second image uses the applied supply voltage of 24V.
Which one is correct?

What Vgs are you applying and when? Or, what is the circuit and load? How fast does it turn on or off?

@OsmarGarnica nS = nanosiemens, a value of conductivity. ns = nanosecond, a value of time duration.

Vgs applyed is -10V (shown in graph). The fet is used as a simple high side load switch, to turn a relay on and off. It will not be switching the load at high frequencies, just turn on and off the relay. The mosfet gate waveform have 100ns rise and 100ns fall time.

No, what are you applying to the real device in a real circuit -- FYI the Vgs condition only applies to the Rds(on)-limited curve (or is at best erroneous anywhere else on the plot).

I´m switching a relay. It will switch it and stay on for hours. You mean, the Vgs of -10V shown in the graph only applies to the left side of the graph below the RDS(on) limited curve? Makes sense, otherwise we cant have a high voltage at Vds with Vgs beign -10V.

@OsmarGarnica : will the coil of the relay really consume 2A @ 24V (ie 48W) for any prolonged period of time? If so, why not choose a relay wasting less energy in the coil? And have you considered the cooling of the relay (most/all relays I have used so far would not withstand 48W of heat generated in the coil). NB : if the 2A are only short transients, then there is no issue

Thanks for the answer. Yes, it will consume this outrageous ammount of power, unfortunately, It is an industrial high power motor relay. I just need to know if the FET can withstand this without smoking.

I think you are mixing the linear state of the FET with the fully on state. For your purposes the FET will practically spend no time with 24VDS AND 2A. i.e. when you have 2A through it, you will be at RDS of <0.1Ohm, so VDS of <0.2V

@WesleyLee I tought the same. The mosfet as switch will drop its Vds voltage to Rds(on) x Id when starts conducting.

A relay coil is inductive, and you can apply 24V across it instantly without any current flowing, initially. That means that there will be very little \$V_{DS}\$ during the entire rise of current from zero to 2A, a regime of operation well within the SOA. Here I switch on the transistor at 50μs, and plot the resulting \$V_{DS}\$ and \$I_D\$:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Drain potential drops instantly, unopposed by the inductance, but current rises slowly as you would expect from an inductor with resistance. There is very little time during which both are simultaneously significant, and their product, power dissipated by M1, looks like this:

The long-term \$I_D\$ and \$V_{DS}\$ are non-zero while the MOSFET is on, and in my example here these are:
$$\begin{aligned}
P &= 400mW \\ \\
I_D &= 2A \\ \\
V_{DS} &= \frac{P}{I_D} = 0.2V
\end{aligned}
$$
As you noted, in your case with \$R_{DS(ON)}=42m\Omega\$:
$$V_{DS}=I_D \times R_{DS(ON)}= 84mV $$
These long-term "on" values are what you would call "DC", and they will necessarily identify a point under the line labelled \$R_{DS(ON)} LIMIT\$. That line is defined by \$V_{DS} = I_D \times R_{DS(ON)}\$, a simple application of Ohm's law. It's impossible to obtain a state above that line, while the MOSFET is as "on" as it possibly can be, because the MOSFET channel is just a resistor now. Therefore, from that graph, if you are passing 2A of current, and your \$V_{GS}\$ is sufficient to obtain minimum \$R_{DS(ON)}\$, then any \$V_{DS}<0.5\$ will lie within the SOA.
When switching the coil off, presumably a snubber or free-wheeling diode (D1 above) will be present to pass all current until it has fallen from 2A to near zero, almost none of which will pass via the transistor. Therefore you'll have a little over 24V of \$V_{DS}\$, but with no current, still well within the SOA:

\$V_{DS}\$ rises instantly to 25V (it would be hundreds of volts without D1) and \$I_D\$ drops almost instantly (almost, because the MOSFET doesn't switch off instantly), but again there's almost no time during which M1 power dissipation is significant:

When the MOSFET is off, obviously \$I_D=0A\$, and you can't possibly be outside the SOA.
Switch-on and switch-off is as fast as the change in gate potential, which shouldn't be more than a few microseconds. Consequently, these transitions do not concern the DC line of the SOA graph; they are too short-lived. Even the 100μs plot is pessimistic, you'd have to exceed \$I_D=10A\$ and \$V_{DS}=40V\$ for a lot longer than a few microseconds, to stress this MOSFET to destruction.

The conclusion then, is that with an inductive load such as a relay coil (with resistance to limit current to 2A), and an appropriate means of dispensing with coil energy at switch-off (D1), the transistor you have chosen will handle that current just fine, while off, while on, and while transitioning (quicker than a few microseconds) between those states.
This won't necessarily be the case for capacitive loads, since unlike inductance, capacitance will oppose the rise and fall of drain potential, leading to extended periods during which channel voltage and current are simultaneously significant.

Thanks for the answer. I will probably switch the relay once a day and will be on for many hours. So the transients should not be a problem, as I have a snubber diode in parallel with the coil. I only need to know if the mosfet will withstand the steady state current of 2A after beign switched on.

@OsmarGarnica It will. Don't apply +24V to the gate though, that will kill the MOSFET. 20V max.

Thanks for the advice. I already have a voltage divider at the gate, i'm using 10-12V max.

The SOA graph is telling you what voltage and current the FET can sustain simultaneously.
At the low voltage / high current end, the SOA graph is showing you that the FET can handle 5 A if you keep the voltage low, below 0.2 V, which the RDSon can support. Your FET is therefore good for hard-switching 5 A.
The high voltage low current end can handle 40 V, a good margin over your 24 V, but only up to a few 10s of mA.
What mode are you going to be operating in? Hard-switching on and off, or continuous dissipation class A mode? They are very different for a FET.
Note that the SOA graph is on log-log scales, that means that straight lines correspond to constant products. In this case, you can dissipate 1 watt indefinitely anywhere from 200 mV x 5 A to 40 V x 25 mA.
There is a rule of thumb for load-line calculations that says if the adjustable element can dissipate 1 watt, then the fixed element can dissipate 4 watts at full voltage. Your load can therefore be 4 watts / 24 V = 166 mA max = 144 Ω for linear continuous class A operation. The maximum control element dissipation occurs at half voltage, when there's 1 watt into both load and control element.
If you want to switch 2 A on and off from a 24 V supply, that's fine, as long as you pass through the high dissipation 2 A x 24 V region from fully on to fully off in a time permitted by the SOA graph. That looks to be about 10 ms, though 1 ms would be safer. Achieving < 1ms switching time in a FET ought to be very easy indeed, it gets difficult when you try to hit us times.
What's the 'correct' switching time to aim for? As the switching time goes down, the energy dissipated during the switching event decreases. For infrequent load switching, that's rarely an issue. For driving a power supply at 10s or 100s of kHz, it's often the limiting factor in the design. You might get away with CMOS or an opamp driving your gate for infrequent switching, whereas a 'gate driver' capable of several amps is usually needed for power supply operation.
Why do FETs have this very restrictive DC performance? A FET is thermally unstable when gate voltage controlled at all but the lowest power, due to the Vgs tempco turning over at a few volts. Most FETs don't even publish a DC line on the SOA graph. If you pass quickly through the high dissipation region, the instability does not have time to spread across the die. Once the FET is hard on, the RDSon tempco ensures stable operation, even to the point of several paralleled devices sharing current stably.

Thanks for the answer. The mosfet will hard switch a relay on and off, and will stay on (DC) for hours. I'll use Vgs = -10V for this.

There are two things to be concerned with. The DC situation and the transient situation. While the MOSFET is switching (on or off) there will be a Vgs plateau with much higher Vds than DC and some portion of 2A flowing. When the MOSFET is switching off where there may briefly be the full current at full voltage (plus a bit) across the MOSFET. SOA is primarily concerned with the transient conditions, but it does have thermal limits and Rds on there too, for one particular situation. You don't need the SOA curve at all for DC, the other numbers on the datasheet are better to use because they don't assume the one fixed condition.
Assuming you have 10V or more gate drive, the 42mΩ you used is a conservative number, guaranteed up to 125°C die temperature.
At 2A we have 168mW maximum, so a temperature rise of 18°C-21°C using the medium or minimum footprints shown in the datasheet. Unless your ambient is going to be extremely hot, that's pretty safe.
The SOA curve comes into play for the transient conditions. The MOSFET can survive 2A at 24V for more than 0.01 second, according to the curve. When turning off there will be a brief time when the current is 2A and Vds is a bit over 24V, before the the catch diode begins to conduct, however that should be much less than 10 milliseconds. Similarly, unless you use a very high resistance value for the gate divider, the plateau due to Miller effect (draining out or supplying that ~42nC of gate charge) when switching should not be of long enough duration enough to be of concern. It's pretty hard to simulate the relay because the parameters such as distributed capacitance and inductance (which varies as the mechanical parts move) are not well documented, but it can be measured to confirm that you're well within the SOA as expected.
Of course, it's easier on the MOSFET to switch it briskly (and to avoid inductive loads, but you can't do much about that).
